# repl.it with secrets not working when I share my code

Tags: python, environment-variables, smtp, replit

I have the following code in replit, this is my first time using replit so I do not know what I'm messing up. I have tried reading the replit documents about enviroment varibles, and I have been working on this for hours and can't figure out what is wrong. My username and passwords are right for the login, i have already checked gmail and made sure APP password is setup.
The thing is the code works when im on replit, but if I share the code, like the link to someone, and they try to run the program it gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
```

I printed the env varibles on replit and it prints out the correct info, i printed the env varible type and they are both strings...so what do I do here im stuck.

```
my_secret = os.getenv("EmailAddy")
my_secret2 = os.getenv("EmailPass")
import smtplib
import os

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Authentication
s.login(f"{my_secret}",f"{my_secret2}")
```

I have tried also doing os.env.get (something like that)
I have tried just doing
s.login(my_secret,my_secrete2)
I have tried generating a new app password from gmail.
..nothin works

Comment: What line does it throws the error on?

Comment: Why do you assume the environment on https://repl.it/ contains values for these variables? How are you setting them?

Comment: @Rishabh the last line, the s.login

Comment: @tripleee replit has a section called "secrets" that is meant for storing env varibles, I used that, and like I said when I print the env varibles it works, it shows me the value that is stored in them

Comment: The point of secrets is that they are secret. Duh.